# Write in Scheme a recursive function to compute the Euler's number e

Tags: recursion, scheme

Write in Scheme a recursive function er, and a non-recursive (based on do-loop) function ei, that take as their argument the number of components n, and compute the following sum (approximation of e) 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + ... + 1/n!, n>0

Comment: That wouldn't happen to be some kind of homework, now would it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you.  I hope that will help you!

```
((lambda (s) (s s -1 1 0))
 (lambda (hep M f! euler-number)
   ((lambda (s)
      (if (= M 20)
          (+ 0.0 euler-number)
          (s s 1 1 (+ euler-number (/ 1 f!)))))
    (lambda (hop N x! euler)
      (hep hop (+ N 1) (* x! N) euler)))))
```

Comment: Could you add a little explanation of how the function works? Not exhaustive, just brief.

Comment: @user5389726598465 it uses a continuation that grows at each loop by a new closure. it loops using the y-combinator.  At each loop it goes up on the current continuation (which at Nth iteration encodes the number N).  This is enough for you to be able to debug now ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is to calculate the factorial, since you are going to need need in the for loop. Then, in the for loop you have to call the factorial function and please see how to do it with a for loop, instead of recursively. The last line of the post below is how to test for the function, which should return the correct number for the factorial of 6.

```
(define (factorial n)
      (cond
        ((= n 0) 1)
        ((* n (factorial (- n 1)))))) 

    (define (ei n)
      (define sum 0)

      (do ((i 0 (+ 1 i)))
         ((> i n))
         (set! sum (+ sum (/ 1. (factorial i)))))

      sum)
```

;(ei 6)